# QGIS2WEB white screen on export/preview?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-plugins

When I export my QGIS2WEB project it goes through, but when it loads up in my browser after the export is done all I see is a white background with the zoom/minus feature in the top left hand of the screen.

[image: From QGIS] [image: From Browser]

Comment: Can you upload a full-res screenshot? I can't see your settings from that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that one layer was using a rule-based renderer, which is unsupported. I need to patch the plugin to alert users if their project contains rule-based layers.

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with a layer displayed as "No Symbols" (I was displaying labels only).  Changing to "Single Symbol" corrected the behavior

Comment: @Brian Fisher Thanks for reporting that - I might be able to fix it in qgis2web (ie handle "No symbols" layers properly).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I was also using a rule-based render which also came out blank. But even if I use a basic plot with no rules with single symbol I still get a blank export. If I remove the layer then the map shows; but as soon as I add the layer the preview and export is blank. I am plotting long and lat across the UK.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265803)